Are `None` and `type(None)` really equivalent for type analysis?
According to the PEP 484's "Using None" part:

When used in a type hint, the expression None is considered equivalent to type(None).

However, I encountered a case where both don't seem equivalent :
from typing import Callable, NamedTuple, Type, Union

# I define a set of available return types:
ReturnType = Union[
    int,
    None,
]

# I use this Union type to define other types, like this callable type.
SomeCallableType = Callable[..., ReturnType]

# But I also want to store some functions metadata (including the function's return type) in a `NamedTuple`:
class FuncInfos(NamedTuple):
    return_type: Type[ReturnType]

# This works fine:
fi_1 = FuncInfos(return_type=int)

# But this issues an error:
# main.py:21: error: Argument "return_type" to "FuncInfos" has incompatible type "None"; expected "type[int] | type[None]"  [arg-type]
# Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
fi_2 = FuncInfos(return_type=None)

# But this works fine:
fi_3 = FuncInfos(return_type=type(None))

It doesn't pose me much problem to write type(None) rather than simply None, but I would've liked to understand the above error issued that seems to contradict the quote from PEP 484.
Snippet available for execution here.

EDIT: It actually seems to boil down to the following:
from typing import Type

a: Type[None]

# This seems to cause an issue:
# main.py:4: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "None", variable has type "type[None]")  [assignment]
# Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
a = None

# This seems to work:
a = type(None)

Snippet available for execution here.

"When used in a type hint" return_type isn't a type hint it's a class variable that happens to hold a type.  None isn't normally a type; it's an object (the only object) of the type NoneType.  Only in the context of a type hint does it have special meaning.

@MilesBudnek Isn't the : Type[None] following return_type still a type hint though? Is it simply None and type(None) are two values of different types, both can't be used interchangeably?

Type[None] and type(None) are not the same thing.  As the sentence you quoted says, None in a type hint is equivalent to type(None), so Type[None] is equivalent to Type[type(None)].  That means a in your edit is a type (specifically NoneType) and None is not a type.

Does this answer your question? Python 3 type hinting for None?

I would consult the up-to-date typing specifications, but even in this case, the wording When used in a type hint, the expression None is considered equivalent to type(None) is pretty unclear. type(None) can never be used in a type hint, of course - it is a call expression (and therefore not an annotation expression).

As showed in the post, the PEP 484 stated something ambiguous:

When used in a type hint, the expression None is considered equivalent to type(None).

But I found out about the PEP 483 that uses a much clearer wording in its Pragmatics:

Where a type is expected, None can be substituted for type(None); e.g. Union[t1, None] == Union[t1, type(None)].

With that in mind, different examples now start to make sense.
For instance, my second MRE:
from typing import Type

a: Type[None]

# This seems to cause an issue:
# main.py:4: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "None", variable has type "type[None]")  [assignment]
# Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
a = None

# This seems to work:
a = type(None)

now can be interpreted as:
from typing import Type

a: Type[type(None)] # Type[...] expects a type.
a = None
a = type(None)

Now, a's type is explicitly "subtype of type(None)", which precisely doesn't match the type of the expression None, hence the error message.
However, it's indeed the type of the second expression: type(None) ("Every type is a subtype of itself." according to the PEP 483 itself).

So, as suggested by some comments, I basically misinterpreted the PEP 484 and forgot that the "equivalence" took effect only "in a type hint" (or "where a type is expected"). Which wasn't the case when passing parameters or making assignments in my snippets.

On an additional note, Type[None] (subtype of None) wouldn't make much sense as None isn't a type (unlinke NoneType) even though MyPy uses the wording "type None" (I would've expected something like "None has type NoneType" rather than "None has type None").

Yeah this was an interesting one.
Part 1: None is strange
I would say it comes down to this: None is really an instance of NoneType, but for practical purposes it should be treated as None itself. Consider the following:
from types import NoneType
x: None = None # succeeds
y: NoneType = None # succeeds in pyright, fails in mypy
z: type[None] = None # fails in both

Weird, right? The second case passes in pyright because it says None is an instance of NoneType, but in mypy the special case is explicitly banned: "NoneType should not be used as a type, please use None instead"
Part 2: Type alias assumes too much with union
It seems that when you define a union that uses None, it assumes that type[None] is a part of the union:
from typing import reveal_type

x = int | None
y = None
reveal_type(x) # type[int] | type[None]
reveal_type(y) # None

This feels like a bug to me - I would have expected reveal_type on x to show:
reveal_type(x) # type[int] | None

...since, as shown above, type[None] isn't exactly a canonical type. But it is what it is, so we'll have to work with it for now.
Part 3: What about the use case?
It occurred to me inspect already implements a similar function so I would take a look at what types the following had:
from inspect import signature

def test() -> int:
    return 1

x = signature(test)
print(x.return_annotation) # int

def test2() -> None:
    pass

y = signature(test2)
print(y.return_annotation) # None

It turns out this doesn't support static typing, but the correct type for these return annotations would be type[int] | None. I would personally special case None if possible:
from typing import Callable, NamedTuple

ReturnType = int | str

SomeCallableType = Callable[..., None | ReturnType]


class FuncInfos(NamedTuple):
    return_type: None | type[ReturnType]

fi_1 = FuncInfos(return_type=int)
fi_2 = FuncInfos(return_type=None)

Hope this helps!

Hello and thanks for this answer.
Part1.example 2:
Seemed motivated by this issue. I didn't really get how semantically (I don't know about the implementation at that time) the provided mre was a problem.

For the rest I actually found a better explanation than the one from PEP484 that explains this behavior better, from the previous PEP (483)'s Pragmatics :
"Where a type is expected, None can be substituted for type(None); e.g. Union[t1, None] == Union[t1, type(None)]."

This seems to indicate that in all the above samples, when provided in a place where a type is expected, None is interpreted as type(None) (NoneType).
So from my second MRE: a: Type[None] = None is interpreted as a: Type[type(None)] = None. Which implies that a expects subclasses of type(None)/NoneType rather than values of type NoneType.
PEP 484 may simply be too strongly worded imho as None and type(None) would precisely not be equivalent.
